# can facebook not detect dynamic content in meta tag?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, facebook-social-plugins

this is my code for specifying content in meta tag. but for some reason facebook is not getting the content in these tags.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $fb_title;?>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?=$fb_link;?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?=$fb_image;?>"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="example"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="app_id"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="<?=$fb_desc;?>"/>
<meta itemprop="image" content="<?php echo $fb_title;?>">
```

this is the content shown in my page's source :->

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<link rel="image_src" href="http://www.example.com/uploads/programsNew/Perte-de-poids-d'environ-10-kg-en-course-à-pied,-2-356.jpg##" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="app_id"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/uploads/programsNew/Perte-de-poids-d'environ-10-kg-en-course-à-pied,-2-356.jpg##"/>

<meta property="og:image:url" content="https://www.example.com/uploads/programsNew/Perte-de-poids-d'environ-10-kg-en-course-à-pied,-2-356.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://www.example.com/uploads/programsNew/Perte-de-poids-d'environ-10-kg-en-course-à-pied,-2-356.jpg" />
```

The errors provided by facebook are:

1.Object at URL 'https://www.'sitename'.com/' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:image:url' of type 'url' was not provided.

2.The following will be treated as a redirect by the crawler:

- A HTTP redirect
- A `<link rel="canonical" href=".." />` tag
- A `<meta property="og:url" content=".." />` tag

In the page source there is no canonical tag, it is present in the main code but inside a condition for another page. so the 'canonical' tag is absent in this page. so why is there an error ,if anybody have any ideas please share.

Comment: What is the real URL you have problem with?

Comment: it's okay i have solved it, you just had to specify the current url of the page  to the og:url tag instead of site homepage .

Answer (score 1):

The `og:url` tag is only the domain, not the permalink. So Facebook actually goes to www.example.com to get the Open Graph tags:

```
<meta property="og:image:url" content=""/>
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="" />
```

Comment: thanks it worked , i changed the og:url tag to current page url instead of the main site domain and the images where loaded.